# What for options list in CTE is used besides aliasing the columns?

Tags: mysql, common-table-expression

Are parameters in Common Table Expressions in MySQL used only for aliasing the columns or is there any other utility they provide?

For example, if I have the following CTE:

```
WITH cte_name (column1_frinedly_name, column2_friendly_name) AS (
    SELECT column1, column2
    FROM tables
)
SELECT *
FROM cte_name;
```

...it returns the same results as:

```
WITH cte_name AS (
    SELECT column1 as column1_frinedly_name, column2 as column2_friendly_name
    FROM tables
)
SELECT *
FROM cte_name;
```

Are there any other reasons one would use the CTE's parenthesized parameters except for renaming the resulting columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also give an alias for columns that have no useful name, like if you use expressions:

```
mysql> with cte (x, y, z) as ( select 1+1, concat('a','b','c'), null ) select * from cte;
+---+------+------+
| x | y    | z    |
+---+------+------+
| 2 | abc  | NULL |
+---+------+------+
```

It's important to declare distinct names for all columns in a CTE. Duplicate column names are not allowed. So if the query defined in your CTE is a join or something, it may be important to give the columns names.